# VisualForce Email Templates

Tags: email, email-template, visualforce-template

I'm facing with VisualForce Email Templates and I need to get the email body with rendered field in order to use it somewhere else.

This is an use case

I've got an email whit this body "Hello {!Account.Name}" and I want to use this body somewhere else with the rendered value of Account.Name, so that in the variable where I store the body I will get "Hello Fabio".

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Savepoint, Try it like this

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

//All FIELD MAPPING

Database.rollback(sp);

String bodyTextWithMergeField = message.getBody();

// bodyTextWithMergeField will have all what you want.
```

Comment: I found a post on this web site where they were talking only about HTML Template, does it work for a VisualForce Template as well?